# Most efficient way to fill missing elements of dataframe with a function of column and row indices

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with missing values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice((0, np.nan), (5, 5)))
print df

     0    1    2    3    4
0  0.0  NaN  0.0  NaN  0.0
1  0.0  NaN  0.0  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  0.0  NaN  NaN
3  0.0  NaN  0.0  0.0  0.0
4  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

#### Question

How do I efficiently fill the missing values with what a function returns when passed the missing cell's row and column index values.

Suppose my function `f` is defined as:

```
f = lambda i, j: i ** 2 - np.sqrt(abs(j))
```

I expect to get:

```
     0    1    2         3    4
0  0.0 -1.0  0.0 -1.732051  0.0
1  0.0  0.0  0.0 -0.732051 -1.0
2  4.0  3.0  0.0  2.267949  2.0
3  0.0  8.0  0.0  0.000000  0.0
4  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000000  0.0
```

I've created two functions so far that generate this output:

```
def pir1(df, f):
    dfi = df.stack(dropna=False).index.to_series().unstack()
    return df.combine_first(dfi.applymap(lambda x: f(*x)))

def pir2(df, f):
    dfc = df.copy()
    for i in dfc.index:
        for j in dfc.columns:
            dfv = df.get_value(i, j)
            dfc.at[i, j] = dfv if pd.notnull(dfv) else f(i, j)
    return dfc
```

#### Timing

---

```
%%timeit
pir1(df, f)

100 loops, best of 3: 3.74 ms per loop
```

---

```
%%timeit
pir2(df, f)

1000 loops, best of 3: 714 µs per loop
```

Can anyone improve on these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `arraymap` in `pir1` and the double for-loop in `pir2` call `f` once for
each pair of index and column values.  If `f` can be vectorized -- i.e. defined
so as to accept NumPy arrays as input instead of scalars, then for large inputs
the calculation can be sped up considerably by passing whole 2D arrays to `f`.

For the `f` you posted, no change is necessary; `f` is already vectorized -- it can
accept arrays as input just as easily as scalars.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice((0, np.nan), (5, 5)))
def f(i, j): return i ** 2 - np.sqrt(abs(j))

def using_meshgrid(df, f):
    I, J = np.meshgrid(df.index, df.columns, sparse=True, indexing='ij')
    return df.combine_first(pd.DataFrame(f(I, J), index=df.index, columns=df.columns))

def pir1(df, f):
    dfi = df.stack(dropna=False).index.to_series().unstack()
    return df.combine_first(dfi.applymap(lambda x: f(*x)))

def pir2(df, f):
    dfc = df.copy()
    for i in dfc.index:
        for j in dfc.columns:
            dfv = df.get_value(i, j)
            dfc.at[i, j] = dfv if pd.notnull(dfv) else f(i, j)
    return dfc
```

---

For small inputs, `pir2` is still the fastest:

```
In [290]: %timeit using_meshgrid(df, f)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.01 ms per loop

In [291]: %timeit pir1(df, f)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.61 ms per loop

In [292]: %timeit pir2(df, f)
1000 loops, best of 3: 825 µs per loop
```

But for large input, `using_meshgrid` is faster:

```
In [293]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice((0, np.nan), (500, 500)))

In [294]: %timeit using_meshgrid(df, f)
10 loops, best of 3: 160 ms per loop

In [295]: %timeit pir1(df, f)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.15 s per loop

In [296]: %timeit pir2(df, f)
1 loop, best of 3: 4.79 s per loop
```

Comment: Interesting to see that pir2 becomes the least efficient of the 3.  Thank you so much for taking the time to think through this and teaching me something extremely valuable.  meshgrid and vectorized functions are now burned into my brain.

Answer (score 2):

Listed in this post is an approach with [`np.nonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) to get those indices and computing the function outputs for those. Also, we would work with `df.values` that extracts out the underlying data as an array as a view, giving us two benefits -

- NumPy funcs/operations could be used on it for good performance.
- Output values could be set as needed for this  problem for filling by just assigning values into the extracted array, being a view into the input dataframe.

Thus, we would have an implementation, like so -

```
def using_nonzeros(df, f):
    a = df.values
    r,c = np.nonzero(np.isnan(a))
    a[r,c] = f(r,c)
```

and the function `f` is customizable and for the stated problem defined like so -

```
def f(i, j): return i ** 2 - np.sqrt(abs(j))
```

Runtime test -

```
In [223]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice((0, np.nan), (1000, 1000)))

In [224]: %timeit using_meshgrid(df,f) # @unutbu's soln
1 loops, best of 3: 823 ms per loop

In [225]: %timeit using_nonzeros(df,f) # This changes df
100 loops, best of 3: 4.61 ms per loop
```